# str_remove to end of multiline string

Tags: r, stringr

How can stringr remove to the end of a multi-line document?

```
require(stringr)
x = 'The quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog'

str_remove(x, regex('jumps.*', multiline = TRUE)) %>% cat
#> The quick brown
#> fox 
#> the lazy dog
```

Comment: Think I'll go with `gsub('jumps.*', '', x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

x = 'The quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog'

str_replace(x, regex('jumps.*\n*.*'), "") %>% cat
```

Should be same as:

```
str_remove(x, regex('jumps.*\n*.*')) %>% cat
```

Comment: This just matches to the end of the next line.  The solution would be `str_remove(x, regex('jumps.*(\n.*)+')) %>% cat`